# Mechanism of updating data in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {},
      dataTemp: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateData() {
      let queries = { ...this.$route.query }
      this.data = {
        ...this.data,
        pID: queries.pid,
        sID: queries.sid
      }
      this.dataTemp = {
        ...this.dataTemp,
        pID: queries.pid,
        sID: queries.sid
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the example above, when I update this.data, this.dataTemp will also be changed.

But I think it is not related to each other.

Please explain to me this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: if you execute `udpateData` you assign an object to `this.dataTemp`. what do you expect

Answer (score 1):

This sets the initial values of `data` and `dataTemp` to empty objects. Note that they are both *different* objects though - `data !== dataTemp`.

```js
data() {
  return {
    data: {},
    dataTemp: {}
  }
}
```

If someone calls `this.updateData()`, both are changed because we assign to both `data` and `dataTemp`. If you only want to update `data`, you could change the method to

```js
updateData() {
  let queries = { ...this.$route.query }
  this.data = {
    ...this.data,
    pID: queries.pid,
    sID: queries.sid
  }
}
```